# Eiffel: are the convert methods working in case of agent call arguments?

Tags: type-conversion, agent, createprocess, eiffel

I'm calling a procedure with an argument which is an integer_64. I implemented a WATT class which can create it from an INTEGER_64 and it seems the execution stops when reached this point, where am I wrong?

`Catcall detected for  argument#1`args': expected  TUPLE [!WATT] but got TUPLE [INTEGER_64]`

[image: code_and_situation]

### Attached case (Update)

Actually when checking with syntax

```
attached {INTEGER_64} my_watt_object as l_int
```

[image]

it doesn't pass either... is it the expected behaviour?

Actually it seems for me that the semantic cases are the same which have to validate the **conformity** step... for me (but seems not to be the case for the definition of the [language between conformance/conformity](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-367.pdf)) which says

> Conformance  and  convertibility  are  exclusive  of   each  other,
>   p.87

Is the conformance rule valid for a type which defines as `convert` a type to another which is my case from WATT to INTEGER_64?

Comment: Can you show the signature of set_from_json_object?
Also resize the grid columns, so feature names are fully displayed.

Comment: @Jocelyn thx, hope this time you got all informations

Comment: I forgot about this post, but in your first screenshot you call a routine agent `set_charge` that accepts WATT with an INTEGER_64 arguments. So the catcall message is expected. For your "update", the implicit conversion is not applied for object test local (otherwise it would be impossible to do `if attached {INTEGER_64} ... elseif attached {WATT} ... `).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eiffel, the conversion specified by the language works only at compile time. It applies if the source of a reattachment does not conform to the target of the reattachment at compile time and there is the corresponding conversion feature.

No automatic conversion is performed at run-time. If you need this functionality, you need to implement it yourself. In your example, if the argument type is `WATT`, you need to call the conversion from `INTEGER_64` to `WATT` explicitly, and pass the object of type `WATT`, not `INTEGER_64`.

Comment: Eiffel is a compiled language, there is no interpreter that evaluates types, performs checks and conversions at run-time dynamically.